# Establecer fecha de inicio de DateTimePicker siempre lunes C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms, datetime

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación Windows Forms en C#. Tengo un `DateTimePicker` que llamaré `dtp1`.

Sucede que lo que necesito es que este `dtp1` siempre tenga como fecha el día Lunes de la semana en curso.

Es decir,

- Si hoy es `Jueves 06/10/2016`, el valor de este `dtp1` debería ser `03/10/2016`.
- Si iniciamos el programa un `Miércoles 12/10/2016`, debe mostrar `10/10/2016`.

Comment: Si agregas el código que tienes actualmente referenciado con tu descripción es mas probable que alguien pueda darte un ayudadita :D

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no eh conseguido hacerlo por eso no cuento con un código para esta situación que planteo.

Answer (score 3):

Pues puedes convertir el dt al lunes y después settearlo en el dtpicker

Traducción de [How can I get the DateTime for the start of the week?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38064/3100840)

> Use un método de extensión. Son la respuesta a todo, tu sabes! ;)
>
> ```
> public static class DateTimeExtensions
> {
>     public static DateTime StartOfWeek(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek startOfWeek)
>     {
>         int diff = dt.DayOfWeek - startOfWeek;
>         if (diff < 0)
>         {
>             diff += 7;
>         }
>         return dt.AddDays(-1 * diff).Date;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Que puede ser utilizado de la siguiente manera:
>
> ```
> DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday);//El que tu necesitas
> DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Sunday);
> ```